# Theory about NAND gate decompose

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, soft-question, open-problem

Recently, I play a game of [Turing completeness](https://turingcomplete.game/) where I utilize various gate circuits such as NAND, AND, and NOT to construct a circuit that satisfies the given truth table.

I didn't learn digital circuits or  relevant content. When I play this game, I want to know whether there are any theory to deal it.  For example, given a truth table, is there any theory to get the circuit with least basic gate (or only Nand gate). It seems to be a bit like graph theory (but the vertices are special).

On the other hand, I know a little about  retina from [From Neuron to Brain](http://library.lol/main/3B4D391F82CB336B77E53AECA5A5E577). The retina responds to certain shapes of light, such as a ring of light. I've always wondered how  build a neural network with neurons that respond to ring of  light  but not solid circle
light.

Of course, I'm not really asking for the details of these questions. I just feel they  may are the thing  not liking analysis and algebra. If I want to deal these questions, what book I should begin from ?

Comment: You can use the rules of Boolean algebra to prove that the nand gate is sufficient by constructing the other gates out of nand gates. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic).

Comment: Any digital logic design text book will cover this to some extent.

Comment: @JohnDouma  I know the nand can constructing the other gates. But for a complex  truth table (multiple input/output), how to get the circuit (only using nand or other restriction (least gates or least connecting and so on)) seemly be hard.

Comment: @lanse7pty The NAND minimization problem is NP-complete, see for example [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/204450) answer on [EESE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If there are at most four inputs, my way (maybe not the most quick) would be based on a Karnaugh map that we can easily create from the truth table.